# Proving that a 5 holed torus is not homeomorphic to a 7 holed torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that a 5 holed torus is not homeomorphic to a 7 holed one

I know  the fundamental groups of each of them but I don't know how to prove that they can't be isomorphic

Comment: What are their fundamental groups? Add this information to your question.

Comment: the fundemental group of  5 holed torus is 10 copies of free products of Z quotiened by the [a,b][c,d]... commutators (where first Z is generated by a second by b and so on...) and that of a seven holed we get the same but 14 copies instead of 10

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3579593/edit) your question to add in any details - comments can be deleted without warning

Comment: Well formatted questions are better received here - a wall of text is harder to read

Comment: You could also try using a coarser invariant whose values are easier to compare, namely the Euler Characteristic

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $\pi_1(T\# \cdots \# T)\cong \mathbb Z *\cdots *\mathbb Z/([a_1, b_1]\cdots[a_n, b_n])$. Now you can take their abelenization and apply classification of finitely generated abelian groups theorem to see that they are not isomorphic.

Comment: I think by five-holed torus, the OP means the connected sum of five tori, not one torus with 5 points removed.

Comment: @hunter, thank you, modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

These two surfaces are closed orientable 2-manifolds, so have genus and Euler characteristic as topological invariants.  (And in this case, either distinguishes these two surfaces.)

As you observe, their fundamental groups are free abelian groups of rank $k$, where $k$ is the number of holes.  You should have a theorem that states free abelian groups of differing ranks are not isomorphic.

Their homology groups are finitely generated abelian groups (i.e. finitely generated modules over a PID), so the [classification theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification) for finitely generated abelian groups might help.  (For instance, the two groups have different ranks.)

The 7-holed torus is homoemorphic to the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Connected_sums) of a 5-holed torus and a 2-hold torus, neither of which is the 2-sphere (the identity for connected sum).

The [pants decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)#Pants_decompositions) of these two surfaces have distinct numbers of pairs of pants.  (This is really a restatement that both are closed and their genera are different.)

Their complements in the 3-sphere are distinguishable.  (Of course, each is homoemorphic to its complements in the 3-sphere, so this fact relies on some other method of discriminating these two surfaces.)

<s>The [cohomology groups](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Torus#Cohomology) of the $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{n}$-holed torus, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{T^2(n)}$ are $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{H^k(T^2(n); \Bbb{Z}) = \Bbb{Z}^{\binom{n}{k}}}$, so their first cohomology groups distinguish them.</s>

---

Update: 21 August 2022

As observed by Michael Albanese, I conflated notation from whatever sources I used when this was written.  For a much better discussion of these (distinct) cohomologies, see [Computing the cohomology ring of the orientable genus $g$ surface by considering a quotient map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099596/computing-the-cohomology-ring-of-the-orientable-genus-g-surface-by-considering) .

Comment: Your final sentence is incorrect. Those are the cohomology groups of $T^n$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : Removed and added reference to a different Question addressing the cohomologies.