# Cohomology isomorphism g-Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to construct a map from the g-Torus $T^g$ to a wedge of g tori $T^1\vee···\vee T^1$ which induces an isomorphism on $H^1(T^1\vee···\vee T^1)\to H^1(T^g)$.

According to Hatcher, the map is
[image]

Is there a formal definition? How does it work on the generators of $H^2(T^1\vee...\vee T^1)$?

Comment: The region in the middle is mapped to the wedge point.

Comment: $H^2(T^g)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H^2(T^1 \vee \dots \vee T^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}^g$. The effect of the quotient map is $q^* (n_1,\dots,n_g) = \sum_{i=1}^g n_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more formal construction:

Let $D_1,\dots, D_g$ be disjoint closed embedded disks in $S^2$, and let $S = S^2 \setminus (\sqcup_i int(D_i))$. Let $H = T^1 \setminus D$ for some closed embedded disk, and for each $i$ choose a homeomorphism $f_i\colon \partial H \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \partial D_i$. Then we can construct the genus $g$ surface as

$$ T^g \cong S \sqcup_{\{f_i\}} (\sqcup_{i=1}^g H). $$
In English, attach $g$ handles to the $2$-sphere. Then the quotient $T^g / S$ is homeomorphic to $\vee_{i=1}^g T^1$.

---

Now since $(T^g, S)$ is a "good pair" in the sense of Hatcher, you can use the fact that $\tilde{H}^*(T^g/S)\cong H^*(T^g, S)$ to prove that the quotient map induces an isomorphism on $H^1$ using the long exact sequence of the pair. Here's what the l.e.s. looks like at the bottom:

$$0 \to H^0(T^g) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} H^0(S) \to H^1(T^g, S) \to H^1(T^g) \to H^1(S) \to H^2(T^g, S) \to H^2(T^g) \to 0 $$
so if we start at $H^1(T^g,S)$ and plug in known values we get

$$ \mathbb{Z}^{2g} \to\mathbb{Z}^{2g} \to \mathbb{Z}^{g-1} \to \mathbb{Z}^g \to \mathbb{Z}$$

Here we've used the facts that $H^*(T^g, S) \cong \tilde{H}^*(\vee_{i=1}^g T^1)$ and $S \simeq \vee_{i=1}^{g-1} S^1$. Now, the first two groups are isomorph*ic*, but we need to know that the map between them is actually an isomorphism and not just injective onto some proper subgroup. Consider the last three groups: the last map surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$ and its kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{g-1}$; the group $\mathbb{Z}^{g-1}$ surjects onto this kernel, and since they are both free with the same rank this map must be injective as well. Therefore the last three groups form a short exact sequence, so the first map must be an isomorphism.

---

To get an explicit description of $H^2(q)$, it will suffice to know the cup product structure for $T^g$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469309/cohomology-ring-of-the-double-torus-genus-two-surface?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2290031/14816)). When $g=1$, $H^*(T^1)$ has elements $\alpha, \beta$ which generate $H^1(T^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a group, and $\alpha \cup \beta$ generates $H^2(T^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. For higher $g$, there are pairs $\alpha_1, \beta_1,\dots,\alpha_g, \beta_g$ which together generate the group $H^1(T^g)\cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$, the product $\alpha_i \cup \beta_i$ generates $H^2(T^g)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ for any $i$, and the products $\alpha_i^2$ and $\alpha_i\cup \beta_j$ for $i\neq j$ are all $0$. In particular $\alpha_i\cup \beta_i = \alpha_j\cup \beta_j$ for any $i,j$.

Now consider $W = \vee_{i=1}^g T^1$: let $a_i, b_i$ be the generators of $H^1$ of the $i$-th copy of $T^1$, so their product generates $H^2$ of the $i$-th copy of $T^1$. Then $q^*(a_i) = \alpha_i$ and $q^*(b_i) = \beta_i$, and since $q^*$ is a ring homomorphism we get $ q^*(a_i \cup b_i) = \alpha_i \cup \beta_i = 1 \in H^2(T^g) $. Then if $c = \sum_{i=1}^g c_i (a_i \cup b_i)$ is an arbitrary element of $H^2(W)\cong \mathbb{Z}^g$, we have

$$q^*(c) = q^*(\sum_{i=1}^g c_i (a_i \cup b_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^g c_i \alpha_i \cup \beta_i = \sum_{i=1}^g c_i $$

Comment: How is defined the cup product structure on $H^*(T^g)$ for the generators of $H^1(T^g)$?

Comment: I don't get why is an isomorphism by the long exact sequence. Because $H^0(S)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H^1(S)\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{g-1}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Jackristin I edited my post with an explanation of how to get $q^*\colon H^1(T^g/S) \cong H^1(T^g)$ from the long exact sequence. For the cup product structure on $H^*(T^g)$, there are a couple of questions/answers on here which cover that, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469309/cohomology-ring-of-the-double-torus-genus-two-surface?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2290031/14816

Comment: Thank you! Last thing: did you find out why the induced map on $H^2$ is the sum?

Comment: I think so, you just need to use the cup product structure. I'm currently writing up my argument.